# R calculating information ratio for multiple stocks in an enviorment

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am able to create a list of daily returns for 4 securities in an environment.  But I don't know how to calculate the rolling Information Ratio for(Ra-Rb): SPY-EFA, SPY-GLD, SPY-TLO, EFA-SPY, EFA-GLD, ... TLO-GLD with n= 20 days using closing prices.  The output needs to be a XTS matrix or data frame with each IR in a column and the date index (n is the sample.size).

Any thoughts on where to start?

```
from_date= "2014-12-31"
to_date= Sys.Date()
pr.env<- new.env()
tickers<- c("SPY","EFA","GLD","TLO")
total_tickers<- length(tickers)

getSymbols(tickers, from = from_date, to= to_date , env = pr.env, src = 'yahoo')
Returns<- eapply(pr.env, function(s) dailyReturn(s))
```

Comment: Just out of interest, did my answer (below) help you?

Answer (score 0):

As you'll see on https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/InformationRatio, you can use the `PerformanceAnalytics` package to calculate information ratio. Here's the example that they use:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(managers)
InformationRatio(managers[,"HAM1",drop=FALSE], managers[, "SP500 TR", drop=FALSE])
```

And that yields the following result:

```
[1] 0.3604125
```

I hope that helps you with your example. Just for background, the `PerformanceAnalytics` package is very helpful for many investment management calculations.